# Need Docker configuration on Render.com to serve static files

Tags: docker, debugging, static, render

Currently the way Docker is set is that Django serves static files i.e. style-sheets etc which takes care of the design of my web app.

When I turn DEBUG Mode off, Django lets the actual server serve static files, for performance --- but currently docker (hosted on Render.com) is not configured to do that --- therefore the website is haywired and the design is all wacked out.

Sorry, I'm a noob.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The WhiteNoise library can help you with this! Check out the [WhiteNoise docs](https://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) or https://render.com/docs/deploy-django#static-files.

> On Render, the internet-facing web server is provided by default and we need a way to host static files using it. In this step, we will set up WhiteNoise which is a highly popular solution for this problem. The following instructions are a short overview of the procedure described in the WhiteNoise documentation.

The WhiteNosie docs or Render's Django Deploy docs will walk you through the process of configuring WhiteNoise to serve your static assets.

This architecture works for most sites, but if you have a very high-traffic site, you might want to explore the [django-stores](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, which you can use to upload static assets at build-time to something like S3 so that they are served from there and allow your Django app to focus on only serving dynamic (non-static) requests.

Comment: thank you! We did end up using WhiteNoise.  I'll also check out django-stores if we end up getting a lot of traffic.

Comment: how were you able to deply your django app on render with docker. i'm having the below error

Sep 22 09:26:55 AM  ==> There was a problem starting your server: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH

Hope you can provide assistance @BluegrassFlash